# How to save the text in a NSTextView when clicking on a button

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, textview, cocoa-bindings

So I have a `textview`, and a button that sends the contents of the `textview` elsewhere.

When I edit the `TextView`, and then hit enter or tab, I can then send that string properly.

However, if I edit the `TextView` and just straight hit the button, the changes I made to the string don't get sent.

I tried changing the action to "Sent on End Editing" and I have bound sent action "textchanged" appropriately, but it isn't working for me yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a better route;
just checked "Continuously Updates Value" in the Bindings inspector under Value.